# How to get pasted value using ngPaste directive when jquery is loaded before angular.js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm having problems when i try to get the pasted data using ng-paste directive.

```
<input ng-model="evidence.url" ng-paste="getEvidenceInfos(evidence, $event.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'))">
```

When the jquery is loaded after angular, it works fine.
How to do when jquery is loaded before angular ?

```
<input ng-model="evidence.url" ng-paste="getEvidenceInfos(evidence, $event)">

$scope.getEvidenceInfos = function(evidence, event) {
  $(event.currentTarget).val() // doesn't work
  $(event.target).val() // doesn't work
}
```

Comment: Well, it looks like you are passing evidence as the first parameter to getEvidenceInfos() but your definition accepts event as the first parameter. Try adding a second parameter to your function and looking at that.

Comment: Sorry, this example is wrong. The function receives two parameters!

Comment: Ok gotcha. Can you be more specific about what you are wanting and what it is doing in actuality? A plunker or fiddle would greatly help as well.

Comment: It's simple, i want to get the user pasted data on input field and get the value on getEvidenceInfos function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When jQuery is loaded before angular, it is used within angular instead of jQuery lite which is built into angular. If full jQuery is used, you will receive a jQuery event. The raw event can be found in the property originalEvent.

```
$scope.getEvidenceInfos = function(evidence, event) {
    var pastedData = event.originalEvent.clipboardData;
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? The docs say that `clipboardData` is supported since IE11. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to share my solution to support browsers without clipboard API. This should work on any browser that angular supports.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" ng-paste="copyPasted($event)">
```

JS:

```
$scope.copyPasted = function ($event){
    if(typeof $event.originalEvent.clipboardData !== "undefined"){
        $scope.handlePastedData($event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
    } else { // To support browsers without clipboard API (IE and older browsers)
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.handlePastedData(angular.element($event.currentTarget).val());
        });
    }
};
```